# Creating and using module "float object not callable" -Python 3.5.1

Tags: python, module, python-3.5, callable

Complete novice here trying to learn. I am supposed to create a module which I believe I have done here:

```
import math

def circum(x):
    return 2 * math.pi * x (format (",.3f"))

def area(x):
    return math.pi * x **2 (format (",.3f"))
```

I have named this module mycircle. 
Now I have to import this module and use it to calculate the circumference and area of a circle. My code for this is:

```
import mycircle

def main():
    radius = float (input ("Please enter the radius of the circle: "))
    circumference = mycircle.circum (radius)
    area = mycircle.area (radius)
    print ("The circumference of the circle is ", format    (mycircle.circum, ",.3f"),  sep="")
    print ("The area of the circle is ", format (mycircle.area, ",.3f"), sep="")

main()
```

However, I am receiving the error:

```
 File "C:/Users/Jameson/Desktop/COP 1000/Chapter 5/54.py", line 26, in <module>
main()
  File "C:/Users/Jameson/Desktop/COP 1000/Chapter 5/54.py", line 21, in main
circumference = mycircle.circum (radius)
File "C:/Users/Jameson/Desktop/COP 1000/Chapter 5\mycircle.py", line 4, in circum
return 2 * math.pi * x (format (",.3f"))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

I can only assume that it is something dumb. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am stuck here.

Comment: There are problems with the way you are using `format` in your `mycircle` module. But you probably shouldn't be trying to format the numbers in those functions - just return the numeric values. That way you can use the results in further calculations, if desired. Only format numbers when you're ready to output them.To learn more about how to use `format`, please see the docs for the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
2 * math.pi * x
```

is a `float`. When followed by a pair of `'()'`, python thinks you are calling it like a function, but `float` is not callable. Hence the error.

To fix it, that line (and a similar line in your `area` function) should be changed to

```
return format(2 * math.pi * x, ",.3f")
```

Also, notice that you are doing the formatting twice: once in `circum` and `area`, and then in `main` when you print. You need to do it only once. It makes more sense to have `circum` and `area` simply return floats, and format the values only when you print them (in `main`).

EDIT:

The two `print` calls are also wrong:

```
print ("The circumference of the circle is ", format(mycircle.circum, ",.3f"),  sep="")
print ("The area of the circle is ", format(mycircle.area, ",.3f"), sep="")
```

`mycircle.circum` and `mycircle.area` are functions, not the circumference and area you have calculated in `main`. These should be changed to

```
print ("The circumference of the circle is ", format(circumference, ",.3f"),  sep="")
print ("The area of the circle is ", format(area, ",.3f"), sep="")
```

Comment: Thanks! Well that solved that. So I changed the code in the module there as reflected and then removed the `format` in the final code. Now I am able to get up to: <br/>

    `Please enter the radius of the circle: 3`<br/>
    `The circumference of the circle is <function circum at 0x0359BF18> .`<br/>
    `The area of the circle is <function area at 0x0359BF60> .`<br/>

Sorry, I'm trying to figure out formatting in comment replies. Don't seem to be doing too well.

Comment: @JamesBelcher Yeah, you should correct those too. See the edited answer.

Comment: Oh wow, okay now I think I see what I did. I thought that before when I did the `area = mycircle.circum (radius)` I was passing the `radius` to the function and that I had to call them again. So what is happening is that I'm passing the `radius` and then no longer need to call them below, right?

Comment: Switched everything around and it's now working. Thank you so much! I was completely misunderstanding the way that the functions worked. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: @JamesBelcher You passed `radius` to `circum` -- in other words, you called `circum` with the argument `radius` --- and assigned the return value to `circumference`. You can just use `circumference` now, no need to call again (unless you want to pass a different value).

Comment: Got it, thank you again. You're a life saver. Do I need to post the final edit of the code? Not sure what the etiquette is here.

Comment: @JamesBelcher No you don't need to post the edit. If you find my answer useful, please kindly accept it :)